# Catch \UnknownControllerException in ZF1

Tags: php, zend-framework, try-catch

I can't get the best way to catch an `\UnknownControllerException`.

I have setup a module system which allows me to configure the application before dispatching...

So using events I can hook into there using `onPreDispatch` event.

```
public function onPreDispatch(EventInterface $event)
{
}
```

How to go on from there?

Answer (score 1):

While I had the question written and going on searching for a solution, I found my way and I'd like to share this.

```
public function onPreDispatch(EventInterface $event)
{
    try {
        $request = $event->get('request');
        if ($request instanceof \Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract) {
            $front = \Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
            // If the Event is not dispatchable, redirect to homepage.
            if (! $front->getDispatcher()->isDispatchable($request)) {
                header('Location: /');
                exit;
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Something else went wrong
        throw $e;
    }
}
```